# Set more than one cookie in the 'Set-Cookie' header in a cloudflare worker header.set('Set-Cookie' function

Tags: cookies, http-headers, cloudflare-workers

I'm trying to use a cloudfare worker to add 2 cookie key/value pairs to the response before sending it to the client.

Unfortunately all documentation for the cloudflare workers says to use the response.headers.set('Set-Cookie',xxx) function to set the cookie value:

```
let response = await fetch(request);
response = new Response(response.body, response);

response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "val1=x; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT; Path='/';");

return response;
```

This only allows you to set one cookie header, and if called twice just overwrites the existing header.

I have tried calling the function twice, only the last value comes in:

```
response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "val1=1; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT; Path='/';");
response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "val2=2; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT; Path='/';");
```

I have tried passing 2 cookies in the one header, separated with a comma, but only one comes in:

```
response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "val1=1; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT; Path='/';, val2=2; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT; Path='/';");
```

I have tried passing 2 cookie key/value pairs, but the first key value is set to "1, val2=2":

```
response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "val1=1, val2=2; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT; Path='/';");
```

None of these work.

The only work around I have found is to bundle the vars up into one variable, and then use JS on the client side to unpack and apply the variable:

```
response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "jsVal={val1:1, val2:2}; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT; Path='/';");
```

.. and then in a js file apply the 2 cookie values. Obviously this is not ideal.

Has anyone had any luck applying 2 separate cookies in one response header via a cloudflare worker? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is `Headers.append()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/append

> The difference between set() and append() is that if the specified
>   header already exists and accepts multiple values, set() will
>   overwrite the existing value with the new one, whereas append() will
>   append the new value onto the end of the set of values.

Comment: Ohh my god, so simple. How did I miss that. Thanks mate. Can confirm this works within a cloudflare worker.